# How do I remove an icon from the system tray in Windows 10, with removing it from the system tray menu as well?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

How do I remove an icon from the system tray in Windows 10, whilst removing it from the system tray menu as well?

You might tell me to use the Settings to open this screen.

[image: select which icons appear in the taskbar]

But the problem with this screen, is that when I set a program to be off, it still appears in the system tray menu when you click the arrow. In Windows 8 and 8.1 programs could be removed from this menu. Why would the feature be removed in Windows 10? Is there a way to remove it from the system tray menu (shown once an arrow is clicked) anyway?

Comment: Some icons you cannot remove, but for those you do not need, remove them from your Startup and they will disappear from both places.

Comment: I don't know what program you are referring to.  If you can't open it because there are no icons.. why even run it?  We call that a service.

Comment: I am trying to remove Acer Care Centre from the system tray including the menu. Also it doesn't appear in Startup on Task Manager but it still runs at startup. And yes I can run it. Why does it matter what program I'm referring to. The program won't let me remove it from the system tray in the settings.

Comment: You can use Autoruns (SysInternals) to manage some startup items. Get Autoruns, install, and run as Admin . See if you can disable Acer Care that way.

Comment: I used Sysinternals Autoruns to disable it from running at startup. Thank you. However I'm still not sure what the program does and why it has to run at startup.

Answer (score 1):

The class of apps in the question are the computer Support apps. They start at startup (or may not start) because that is how the manufacturers designed them.

**Lenovo Vantage** is for Lenovo computers and it can be hidden (Windows 10 Settings), or uninstalled, or have startup controlled by Autoruns.

**Acer Care** is a generic tool like Lenovo Vantage. It (likely) looks after Battery, Drivers and such like.

**The HP Support Assistant** is for HP and helps to keep your HP computer in working order by finding updates and providing troubleshooting tools.

**The ASUS ZenUI Support** app is for ASUS is a customer service app the the others.

*(NB)  I have and use Lenovo. I looked up the others using Google but I am familiar with them.*

But now you have your answer:  Use Autoruns (or Startup Manager in Task Manager for things it can manage) and remove your app from starting up. If you do not need the app at all, it can be uninstalled (Start, Settings, Apps in most cases).

Now it will not show up in the Task Bar or in Hidden Icons - that is, neither place as you asked for in your question.

I trust this helps.

Comment: Do you also know, by any chance, the HP and Asus equivalents of Lenovo Vantage?

Comment: No, I do not know them by name, but on either machine (certainly the HP) it should be apparent.  I do not know if ASUS has such an app.

Comment: I don’t own any but I wish to know about their names, helps when answering questions.

Comment: I added information from my own experience to help others when looking at this question.