# Permanently remove an icon from Windows 11's notification area

Tags: windows-11, notification-area

Is there any way in Windows 11 to permanently remove an icon from the notification area?

[image]

In settings, if I am not mistaken, you can only decide whether an icon will be directly visible or hidden inside corner overflow menu.

[image]

So, is there anything that I can do to remove them permanently? Except for [uninstalling the corresponding apps](https://superuser.com/a/1591305/156554) and using some 3rd party software (if such thing exists at all)?

Comment: Many apps have an option to disable the taskbar icon, including NVIDIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Permanently remove an icon from Windows 11's notification area

Apps always have icons, so you cannot permanently remove icons from where they show. The App icon is normally how the app is opened.

If an icon is a system icon, it will be subject to system icon rules and will show unless you hide it.

You can hide them in the Windows 11 Up arrow if they are System Icons (Nvidia is a System Icon).

That is really all you can do.

[image: System Icons]